# WPF can't find resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a question about finding resources in WPF, and I read the mechanism of finding resources from book.

> It said that a UIElement will find its resources attribute first, if nothing fit then it will find its parent's resources attribute and so on, till application resources attribute.

I think it just like bubble routed event.

So I define a resource in stackpanel, here is the xaml.

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicResource.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicResource"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBlock x:Key="res1" Text="this is staticresource" Background="Beige"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Key="res2" Text="this is dynamicresource" Background="DarkGoldenrod"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <Button Margin="5,5,5,0" Content="{StaticResource res1}"></Button>
    <Button Margin="5,5,5,0" Content="{DynamicResource res2}"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="button" Margin="5,5,5,0" Content="refresh resource" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Then I try to change dynamic resource in the button click event, here is xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Can find target resource
        //stackPanel.Resources["res1"] = new TextBlock() { Text = "this is new staticresource", Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Tan) };
        //stackPanel.Resources["res2"] = new TextBlock() { Text = "this it new dynamicresouce", Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta) };

        //Can't find target resource
        button.Resources["res1"] = new TextBlock() { Text = "this is new staticresource", Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Tan) };
        button.Resources["res2"] = new TextBlock() { Text = "this it new dynamicresouce", Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta) };
    }
}
```

But the resource of button didn't change.

So what cause this happened, and how could to bubbly find resources.

Comment: `error CS0103: The name 'button' does not exist in the current context`. It is not clear from your code, which fails to compile, what it is you are actually trying to do. What do you expect `button` to refer to?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. If you change the code above so that the code using `stackPanel` is uncommented and the code using the **undefined** `button` is commented, then the button with the dynamic resource _is_ updated when you click the third button, just as expected. Please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve], and explain precisely what that code does now, what you want instead, and what specifically you have been unable to solve.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm sorry that I lost some code of xaml.

Comment: @PeterDuniho  I edit the question, and this example should be work.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm confused about why does button can't find the resources of stackpanel. I mean ,the button doesn't have resource attribute so it should find resource attribute from his parent ,grandparent  and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must set name for button and use this name in code behind

in xaml:

```
<Button Margin="5,5,5,0" Name="btnRes2" Content="{DynamicResource res2}"></Button>
```

in code behind :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnRes2.Resources["res2"] = new TextBlock() { Text = "this it new dynamicresouce", Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta) };
}
```

this code work for DynamicResource.

Comment: I'm sorry that I lost the name of third button, and I edit this question. When I click the third button which have a name, the resources doesn't change. Because the button can't find res2, however it should find its resources first, if there is nothing fittable, the button should find its parent's resources and so on, just like routed event.

Comment: you must set name other button and use it.because your code into Button_Click.this act is work for dynamicResource